# BasicExtractor problem SpringBoot Intellij vs Jar file

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, maven, modelmapper

I have a very frustrating problem on my SpringbootApp.
Sorry if I don't post code, but I don't know what I should write and if I'm having an error or perfomance problem.

```
2020-02-02 18:30:55.891 TRACE 8964 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [TIMESTAMP] - [Mon Mar 13 00:00:00 CET 2017]
2020-02-02 18:30:55.891 TRACE 8964 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [FOOTBALL]
2020-02-02 18:30:55.892 DEBUG 8964 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.loader.Loader              : Result set row: 0
2020-02-02 18:30:55.892 DEBUG 8964 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.loader.Loader              : Result row: 
2020-02-02 18:30:55.892 TRACE 8964 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([col_0_0_] : [BIGINT]) - [37]
```

This is my dead moment of the app...

If I use Springboot launcher of intellij everything works and fast, if I use jar file, noway to pass and timeout error.

Someone can help me? IF you need to see code or configurations let me know, I supposed many and many hypothesis but I still can't figure out the problem.
I believe to set everything ok, app work from a long time, it happens only on this case, other similar situations work.

PS this is during modelMapper convert from domain to DTO of complex entity, problem still live also removing all collection attributes and just leaving poor info...

Thank you very much

Comment: After other research, I figure out that there is no difference between intellij spring launcher and jar, just in second case it must load all entities, become too slow and got an error...then, it take in cache this, and is no possible to complete this branch of logic....

Comment: Now, the problem is become related to entity management with hibernate, i found this interesting article, maybe I just need optimize my architecture on domain and relationships https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-common-performance-problems-in-logs ... someone know about perfomance common problems? thank you